# Windows 10 startup suddently extremely slow (especially explorer and filesystem related stuff)

Tags: windows-10, ssd, windows-explorer, freeze, hijack

two days ago my PC started to really lose lots of its speed expecially on the startup. At first i was able to fixit just by killing the explorer right after logging in and just restarting it. I tought it just froze on something, like it happens sometimes. Yesturday it got worse, I couldnt even kill and restart it, because even the taskmanager became unrespondant. After a long time and a Restart everything seemed okay again.

Today its just horrible. I have to wait like 30 minutes to get it even responding in the first place. All desktoppicons gone white papers (but one after another reappearing correctly, after total approx. 1.5hrs) and the task bar takes 10 minutes to load up and be functional too.

what I tried so far:

- Windows Updates
- CHKDSK /r /f
- AV-Scans
- SFC /scannow
- cleared >100GB of Space on the sysdrive
- Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth & Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth (No damage found)
- looked at fragmentation of all of my Storage devices (all fine but the large one taking ages to analyze)
- several reboots

Im Running Windows 10 Pro (21H1, Build 19043.1110) on a local machine, as local administrator, with no AD, or Domain whatsoever. C (system) Drive is an 1TB SSD, I have 48 GB of Ram and an I9 9700K. Autostart has only a few programs in it.

EDIT:

I found out that the problem is caused by my biggest HDD (3TB), when unplugged, everything is running smooth again. Now Im trying to figure out what to do with it, to make it work again, since I wasnt even able to run a chkdsk on it (CMD unresponsive).

Comment: If you boot into Safe Mode does the same behavior exhibit itself?

Answer (score 1):

> lose lots of its speed expecially on the startup. At first i was able
> to fixit just by killing the explorer right after logging in and just
> restarting it.

This is very likely a context error. This is how File Explorer and Task Manager (and some others) behave when context handling goes wrong. It can be very difficult to find a specific context error because there are so many context handlers.

Try the following approach (I have used this before).

(1) Make a new, test Windows User Profile (Account). Log into the new Account and see if the hanging behavior persists.

If so, copy the data, favorites, email and documents to a neutral location (say, c:\temp). Make a new user profile and recover your data.

If not, then:

(2) Run a Windows 10 Repair Install.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run.

Use the option to Keep Everything to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for the Input, I tried creating a new profile, what seemed to be good at first but after a while it still wasnt. 
I found out that the problem is caused by my biggest HDD (3TB), when unplugged, everything is running smooth again. Now Im trying to figure out what to do with it, to make it work again..

Comment: Now do the repair install step.

Comment: You might try the repair install without the drive plugged in. When done try the drive again

Comment: So you are saying I should try the repair install without the faulty drive plugged and then reboot with it connected to check if it works again? I wonder how this would repair a fault in the drive and im also a little scared to lose any data because I never did such an install-repair. Does it leave my data untouched or will it be like after a new install in an windows.old-folder?

Comment: If the machine works just fine without the drive, and also a new User Profile fixed the initial problem, then you may wish to just leave the drive disconnected. If you wish to do a Repair, use the Keep Everything option and Windows.old allows you to roll back. I have not lost data to a Repair. I always keep backups, but I have never lost anything.

Comment: Oh sorry, maybe that was unclear. The new User Profile didnt actually help. Only disconnecting the drive itself did. Im actually thinking on getting an external case and some new HDD to mirror my data, mabye over a small workstation that can endure the very long loading times without bothering me on my main PC.